# Unbiased estimate for a parameter

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, estimation, parameter-estimation

They ask me to estimate any parameter and I do not if the solution is correct:

The life time X of a battery is considered to be a random variable with density function

$f (x; Θ) =\frac{ 2 }{ Θ²} (Θ - x)$      if 0 < x <Θ

Be X1, X2, ..., Xn a simple random sample of X. Knowing that $E(X) = \frac{Θ}{ 3}$ and $E(X²) = \frac{Θ²}{6}$, determine:

(a) An unbiased estimator for Θ, Θ ^

(b) The variance of the estimator Θ ^

For (A) I have

$\mu= \frac{Θ}{3}$

$ Θ=3 \mu$

$ Θ= 3 X$

$E(Θ)= E(3X)  $

$ 3 E(X)= 3 *\mu$

$3 * \mu =3 *  \frac{Θ}{3} =  Θ$

(that if it is unbiased)

For (B) I have:

$Var(Θ)= Var(3X) = 3^2 Var(X) = 9 σ^2 /n$

Comment: Similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3038477/unbiased-estimate-for-a-parameter

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, you have a sample from $X$, so your chosen estimator should be based on the sample $X1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ rather than on the underlying $X$

Although you did not say so, you seem to have chosen $3\bar{X}=\frac3n\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i$ as your estimator of $\Theta$.  This does indeed have an expectation of $3 E[\bar{X}] =3 E[X] = \Theta$ so is unbiased.

You may have miscalculated the variance of $X$ which is $\text{Var}(X) = E\left[X^2\right]-\left(E[X]\right)^2 = \frac{\Theta^2}{6}-\left(\frac{\Theta}{3}\right)^2 = \frac{\Theta^2}{18}$ so the variance of your estimator is $\text{Var}(3\bar{X}) = 9\text{Var}(\bar{X}) = \frac{9}{n}\text{Var}(X) = \frac{\Theta^2}{2n}$

Alternatively you might have chosen $3X_1$ or something similar as your estimator.  That would have mean $3 E[X_1] =3 E[X] = \Theta$ so is also unbiased. Its variance is $\text{Var}(3X_1) = 9\text{Var}(X_1) = 9\text{Var}(X) = \frac{\Theta^2}{2}$